# How to target ::before and ::after pseudo elements in Internet Explorer 9 Developer Tools?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

When inspecting elements in IE9 Developer Tools I can't see the pseudo elements I have defined in my CSS in the HTML pane:
[image: IE9 HTML pane]

However I can see them in the CSS pane, but they have strike-through suggesting the styles are being overridden, and hence have no effect when modifying them.
[image: IE9 CSS pane]

How do I target ::before and ::after elements for inspection in IE9?

Note: this may appear to be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19008309/inspecting-pseudo-elements-in-internet-explorer) but in my case the elements are div container elements, so I don't think the answer to that question applies here.

Comment: Pseudo elements aren't real elements! Hence they are only visible in the `css` section of the dev tools.

Comment: Sure, but Chrome Developer Tools chooses to show them in the HTML section. Ok, so I'll accept that IE doesn't choose to show them there. But then the question remains: is there a way around the fact that they are strikethrough / ineffective in the CSS section?

Comment: the strikethrough suggests they are being overwritten somewhere else in the document.

Comment: Yes, that's what I would have thought. If I inspect the same element in Chrome however, there's no strikethrough, nothing with the same classes further up the cascade. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/simbasounds/z7s05znv/2/
- If I inspect the .site-container selector in IE9, then click on the :before pseudo element in the CSS pane it has the strikethrough behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from another answer:

> IE 9 supports the notations ::after and ::before (with two colons) in “standards mode”. In “quirks mode”, it does not.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14145917/5973334

So the only possible reason would be for something in you code to have activated the “quirks mode”